# Why is session not saved in a simple hello world example web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, session

I have the following web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Test : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public void SetSession()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"] = true;
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public bool IsSessionSaved()
    {
        var temp = HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"];
        return temp != null;
    }
}
```

Note I have the `EnableSession = true`.

On my client I have added a Web Service Reference NOT a Service Reference.

[image]

*Note*: In order to create a web service reference instead of the default service reference that visual studio adds for you I followed this steps.

and on my client console appication I have:

```
var client = new Test();

client.SetSession();

bool isSessionSaved = client.IsSessionSaved();
```

Why is `isSessionSaved = false`?

**Update:** I don't think the problem is in the web service it works if I invoke the methods through the default website. I am sure the client is not saving the cookies. Perhaps I need a cookie aware client. I might need to modify the client.

Comment: What is the session configuration from your `Web.config`?

Comment: Sessions work great on web service. I think it is the client that is not saving the cookies :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session state runs off of the session cookie, in order to support cookies you need to add a cookie container to your soap client.

```
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    client.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
```

On a WCF service client the equivalent would be setting allowCookies="true" on the httpbinding configuration.

Comment: The client code is autogenerated. I cannot modify it. Its a web service reference... Thanks for the help!

Comment: You do it when instantiating the client in your code.

Comment: var client = new Test();
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    client.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    client.SetSession();

    bool isSessionSaved = client.IsSessionSaved();

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Session configuration on IIS.

This is the link: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725624(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725624%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Do I do that even if I am still in developing mode? that code is not running on IIS